# Изменение wal autocheckpoint в sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Не могу найти параметр для изменения wal autocheckpoint и checkpoint. `wal_autocheckpoint = n;checkpoint = full;` не работает.

Comment: Судя по документации всё тривиально, https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_autocheckpoint. Может опубликуете код?

Comment: Тогда сразу вопрос. Как я понимаю при добавлении определенного количества транзакций происходит выполнение этих транзакций. То есть я могу это увидеть только по небольшой задержке между выполнением запросов к бд? Может у меня все работает, а я туплю.